# How to connect a power supply on the battery socket of a laptop?

Tags: batteries, power-consumption

I am doing some long-term measurements of power consumption on a laptop. Down below I show a photo of the battery connection pins.

I am trying to trick the laptop into thinking that runs on the battery; you have the schematic diagram of the circuit (without the power measuring circuit).

But with the following setup doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I don't know what kind of data takes the laptop from C1,C2,C3.

Can someone help?

[image: Laptop battery connector and battery socket]
[image: Laptop battery circuit]

Comment: Impossible to say; it's not standardised and usually not public information. It will be communicating with the battery somehow.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @user2613971 Didn't start but now I fixed it. I'll post an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller Just because you have 2 "black-boxes" doesn't mean it isn't a electric/electronic design situation?

Comment: If I had to take a wild guess, I might suspect that the C1, C2, C3 are balance taps at the intermediate connections of a 4-cell lithium battery, used to safely bring each cell up to ideal charge without overcharging the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the fact that I didn't connect the ground of the battery with the ground of the power supply, once I did that it works.

This is the correct schematic diagram with the grounds connected:
[image]